# How to resolve the “Invalid Privacy Policy URL” error

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

When building the Facebook login function, we recognize that it is essential to set the privacy policy URL.
I'm currently building , but when setting the URL, I get an error saying "Privacy policy URL is invalid."
Please tell me the cause and solution for this error.
And How can I check the effectiveness of URL.
*I would appreciate it if you could also tell me about Facebook's official documentation related to this matter.

■Display Error
・Invalid Privacy Policy URL
You must provide a valid Privacy Policy URL in order take your app Live. Go to Basic Settings and make sure it is valid.

■The following have been confirmed
・The privacy policy page must be published in a globally accessible environment.
・When using Facebook's share debugger function, the response code is returned in the 200s.

Could you give me your advice on this matter.

Comment: If their scraper can read it and gets a 200 OK response, that should be enugh.